# Why is the second return statement being called and why am I getting the return error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two uitableviews not related to each other at all, but they are on the same view. The animal tableview is showing the information, but animallocation is not displaying anything. I put a breakpoint on the second return statement in the second if statement, but the program does not stop. I am also getting an error (Look below). How do I fix this? the first if statement works. animallocationarray is populated it prints ("Africa", "India", "South America"). I get an error http://puu.sh/mNK2J/549dde1225.png

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableView == animal){
     var cell: animalCell = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! animalCell
    cell.box.text = animalarray[indexPath.row]
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor = RGB("ffffff")


    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = RGB("F98233")

    }


    return cell

    }
    if(tableView == animallocation){
        var cell: location = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location") as! location
        cell.label.text = animallocatioarray[indexPath.row]
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            cell.label.textColor = RGB("fffff")

        }

        if(indexPath.row != 0){
            cellvs.vslabel.textColor = RGB("f52654")

        }


        return cell //placed a breakpoint here but nothing happens 
    }

}
```

Comment: If you use "if" inside cellforrowatindexpath you should use either "else" case or common return cell outside if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You miss case Default. You can edit

```
if(tableView == animal){
 var cell: animalCell = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! animalCell
cell.box.text = animalarray[indexPath.row]
if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
    cell.backgroundColor = RGB("ffffff")


}else{
    cell.backgroundColor = RGB("F98233")

}


return cell

}
if(tableView == animallocation){
    var cell: location = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location") as! location
    cell.label.text = animallocatioarray[indexPath.row]
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.label.textColor = RGB("fffff")

    }

    if(indexPath.row != 0){
        cellvs.vslabel.textColor = RGB("f52654")

    }


    return cell //placed a breakpoint here but nothing happens 
}
```

To:

```
if(tableView == animal){
 var cell: animalCell = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! animalCell
cell.box.text = animalarray[indexPath.row]
if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
    cell.backgroundColor = RGB("ffffff")


}else{
    cell.backgroundColor = RGB("F98233")

}


return cell

}

var cell: location = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location") as! location
 cell.label.text = animallocatioarray[indexPath.row]
 if(indexPath.row == 0){
     cell.label.textColor = RGB("fffff")

 }

 if(indexPath.row != 0){
    cellvs.vslabel.textColor = RGB("f52654")

 }


 return cell //placed a breakpoint here but nothing happens
```

Comment: I also placed a breakpoint on `var cell: location = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location") as! location` but nothing happens, I think since the first if statement is met nothing happens after.

Comment: @stackerleet I just let help you resolve error. Breakpoint no call, problem is with your table. Your have add more infor about two kind table of you and how to you create it.

Answer (score 0):

The function must return a `UITableViewCell`. Within your code you have two `if` statements. In the event that both of them fail, no `return` statement would be executed. That's why your seeing the error - it is a compilation error if there are code paths that do not return the required type.

In your case, one of the two `if` statements will always be true, but the compiler can't know that. If you recode the second to be an `else`, instead of another `if`, there will be no code paths that don't return a value. i.e.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (tableView == animal) {
        // animal code
        return cell
    } else { // i.e. if (tableview == animallocation)
        // animallocation code
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with below code.**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableView == animal){
         var cell: animalCell = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! animalCell
         cell.box.text = animalarray[indexPath.row]
         if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
             cell.backgroundColor = RGB("ffffff")
         }else{
             cell.backgroundColor = RGB("F98233")
         }
         return cell
    }
    else{
        var cell: location = self.reviews.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location") as! location
        cell.label.text = animallocatioarray[indexPath.row]
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            cell.label.textColor = RGB("fffff")
        }
        else if(indexPath.row != 0){
            cellvs.vslabel.textColor = RGB("f52654")
        }
        return cell //placed a breakpoint here but nothing happens 
    }
}
```

**In you case, you are returning the cell in if condition,
but also we have to consider the case where if condition will not true, 
i.e. else part.**

Comment: Edited the answer, please check

Comment: else is only executed if the if statement fails, but it will always succeed. Should I use a switch instead so both are executed?

Comment: have you set the data source and delegate for both tableViews ?

Comment: can you please edit your question and provide all tableview datasource and delegate methods ? if possible please provide your full viewController code, so we can identify logical error if any